# Add a consul dependency to existing spring boot application in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, consul, service-discovery

I am trying to add "Service Discovery" using consul in my Spring Boot (Maven) application but unable to use ***@EnableDiscoveryClient***. Since, I am new to Intellij I am not sure what I am missing.

Added pom.

I did the following:

1. Added consul dependency in my pom.xml

[image]

2. Tried to re-import maven dependencies. See below:
   [image]

   > ```
   >     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   > <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   >   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   >   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   >   <parent>
   >       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   >       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   >       <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
   >       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   >   </parent>
   >   <groupId>com.mancala</groupId>
   >   <artifactId>MancalaFrontend</artifactId>
   >   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   >   <name>MancalaFrontend</name>
   >   <description>Front-end service for Mancala game.</description>
   >
   >   <properties>
   >       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   >       <vaadin.version>14.1.23</vaadin.version>
   >   </properties>
   >
   >   <dependencies>
   >       <!-- Actuator -->
   >       <dependency>
   >           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   >           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   >       </dependency>
   >
   >       <!-- Web Starter -->
   >       <dependency>
   >           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   >           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   >       </dependency>
   >
   >       <!-- Consul  -->
   >       <dependency>
   >           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   >           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
   >       </dependency>
   >
   >       <!-- Vaadin -->
   >       <dependency>
   >           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   >           <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   >       </dependency>
   >
   >       <!-- Test -->
   >       <dependency>
   >           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   >           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   >           <scope>test</scope>
   >           <exclusions>
   >               <exclusion>
   >                   <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
   >                   <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
   >               </exclusion>
   >           </exclusions>
   >       </dependency>
   >   </dependencies>
   >
   >   <!-- Vaadin Dependency Management-->
   >   <dependencyManagement>
   >       <dependencies>
   >           <dependency>
   >               <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   >               <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
   >               <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
   >               <type>pom</type>
   >               <scope>import</scope>
   >           </dependency>
   >       </dependencies>
   >   </dependencyManagement>
   >
   >   <build>
   >       <plugins>
   >           <plugin>
   >               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   >               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   >           </plugin>
   >       </plugins>
   >   </build>
   >
   > </project>
   > ```

Comment: Do not use pictures better use posted text..furthermore does your project build on plain command line?

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully by "build on plain command line"

Comment: Have you tried to build in plain console via `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: How do you do that? @khmarbaise

Comment: There is no artifact version. Have you added dependencyManagement for spring-cloud? If you need more help, share your entire pom.

Comment: @Lesiak - I have added the pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have't specified artifact version for `spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery`.

NOTE: you didn't have to specify versions for Spring Boot artifacts, because the parent pom has dependency for them. Consul starter is part of Spring Cloud and Spring Cloud version needs to be managed separately

There are 2 ways to do it

- directly in dependency, via `version` tag
- in `dependencyManagement` tag

I encourage you to take the latter approach, Spring provides an include with all Spring Cloud dependencies in compatible version. 
To do it:

- Add `<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>` in `<properties>`
- Add the following in `dependencyManagement`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I generated the pom with desired dependency on [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) page selecting Spring Boot version from your pom to obtain matching Spring Cloud version